# Google Sheet Not Ordering Correctly with "Sort A->Z"

Tags: google-sheets

When I select column 'A' and "Sort Sheet A->Z" it moves #741 to the top of the sheet. Nothing else has this issue.

[Sheet with issue.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X60zk-E27ptsNltY4Y55rEfynHgHJiEcZDGI5M-veuM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try not to post 3rd party links, but rather just post the cells as an image directly on the question post :)

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The `#` character has a lower ordinal position than `A` or `7` under ASCII and Unicode:

```
# = 35
A = 65
7 = 55
```